# Get row of database(phpmyadmin) datatable using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium driver . How to get data of row from database table. I tried this code where my database name is "demodatabase" , table name is "state" and row id is 2

```
package com.db;

import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;



public class DbConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

        /*------connection url----*/
        String dbUrl= "jdbc:mysql://localhost/demodatabase";

        /*------dbUsername----*/
        String dbUsername= "root";

        /*------dbPassword----*/
        String dbPassword= "";

        /*------db query---*/
        String query= "select * from states where id=2";

        /*-----load Mysql jdbc driver------*/
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


        /*----Get connection to DB*/
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUsername, dbPassword);

        //create statement object
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        //send sql query to database
        ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(query);


        // while loop to get ResultSet all rows data
        while(rs.next()){
            String state =rs.getString("2");
            System.out.println(state);
        }

        //Close db connection

        con.close();
    }

}
```

**Database table Screenshot**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcaGc.png

Using above code and database screenshoot .I am getting data of id=2 and column 2  i.e Jharkhand only but I want all data of row 2

Comment: this question has nothing to do with selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above code you have not got the column values of the table's second row

Kindly refer the below code

package com.db;

```
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;



public class DbConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

        /*------connection url----*/
        String dbUrl= "jdbc:mysql://localhost/demodatabase";

        /*------dbUsername----*/
        String dbUsername= "root";

        /*------dbPassword----*/
        String dbPassword= "";

        /*------db query---*/
        String query= "select * from states where id=2";

        /*-----load Mysql jdbc driver------*/
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


        /*----Get connection to DB*/
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUsername, dbPassword);

        //create statement object
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        //send sql query to database
        ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(query);


        // while loop to get ResultSet all rows data
        while(rs.next()){

            //Store columns state,country,created,modified as separate strings 

            //(pls chk spellings of column name and also datatypes of the column if it is int change it to (rs.getInt) before running)

            String state =rs.getString("name");
            String country =rs.getString("country_id");
            String created_DATE= rs.getString("created");
            String modified_DATE=rs.getString("modified");
            System.out.println(state);
            System.out.println(country);
            System.out.println(created_DATE);
            System.out.println(modified_DATE);
        }

        //Close db connection

        con.close();
    }

}
```

Hope this helps you...Kindly get back if it is not working

Comment: @vnnogile oh that's gr8...happy to be of help